# disable anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about putting a link on a page that changes the url, but doesn't change the page without using hash states?

I want to put links that change the url and scroll to a corresponding section of the page. I don't want to use hashes as they just jump to the section instead of scrolling, and I think hashes dont look very good in the url.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @Blazemonger pushState does actually allow you to display a different URL to the 'real' (original) URL, provided it has the same scheme and domain (that's the security aspect). You can see this on the demo here http://html5demos.com/history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [HTML5 Push State](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

There is no other way as far as I know.

Comment: was hoping to be able to do it without push states, but it looks like the pretty unanimous answer to that possibility is no.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the jQuery ScrollTo plugin? http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Comment: [the scrolling isn't the issue](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/01/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin/), that can be done without a plugin. the problem is the url change

Answer (score 1):

Browsers now have security features that ensure that the URL displayed in the location bar matches what's actually being displayed. You can't change the location without changing the page at the same time.

However, you can scroll the page anywhere you like without changing the URL. To scroll to a particular element, get its position and use `.animate()`:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#element').position().top});
```

​
Combine this with an `.on('click',...)` handler that uses `e.preventDefault()` to cancel the URL change and you're good to go.

```
$('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e) { // apply to all hash links
    var el = $(this).attr('href');        // get the href
    e.preventDefault();                   // cancel default click action
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(el).position().top   // scroll to the href ID instead
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/WFKUE/

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 browser history (aka PushState) is the modern approach

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

It is fairly widely supported in browsers

http://caniuse.com/history